# controller key on routes definition missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I added an `erb` file to my app under views/pages.

And then I added the routes like below in my `routes.rb` file.

```
  get '/pages/track-my-order'
```

But I am getting the below error

> Missing :controller key on routes definition, please check your routes.

What's wrong in the routes?

Comment: The purpose of routes is to tell rails "Urls like this should be handled by controller X, action Y".  So you always need some info about which controller/action handles it.

Comment: On it. Thanks @MaxWilliams

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
get '/pages/track-my-order' => 'pages#track-my-order'
or
get '/pages/track-my-order' => 'controller_name#action'
```